# How can you add or change the keys for the owner of an account?

Tags: cleos, permissions, keys

1. How can I change the owner of an account?
2. Can an account have more than one owner?

I see that `active` and `owner` are groups so theoretically there can be multiple keys in either group.

But how can I add a second key to the owner group?

This command fails:

`cleos set account permission account_name owner '{"threshold": 1, "keys": [{"key": "EOS_public_key", "weight": 1}],"weight":1}]}' owner -p owner`

It fails complaining the keys are not in the wallet or that the wallet is not unlocked, neither of which are true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To **change** the owner key, you can use this command:

`cleos set account permission account_name owner EOS_public_key_of_new_owner -p account_name@owner`

**Multiple owners** on an account is essentially a multi-sig account, it's possible and it's described here [Accounts and Permissions](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Accounts%20%26%20Permissions#authorities-and-permissions)

As a concrete example, **to configure two keys** to the owner group of an account you can use this command:

`cleos set account permission account_name owner '{"threshold" : 100, "keys" : [{"key": "EOS_Public_Key1","weight": 50}, {"key": "EOS_Public_Key2","weight": 50}]}' -p account_name@owner`

where `EOS_Public_Key1` and `EOS_Public_Key2` can be either new keys or keys that were already associated with that account.

There are some more examples for `cleos set account permission` in the developers.eos.io [reference docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-set-account)

Comment: Do you have any indication why the OP's command failed?

Comment: I don't, but fwiw the `cleos set account permission` command takes some getting used to. It accepts several variations for how you pass the parameters depending on what you're doing, and it's **very** easy to get it wrong. And the  error messages are only helpful if you are already well versed with how account permissioning works in eos.

Comment: @Vlad do you know if this action can be performed outside of cleos? Specifically if this can be done using the eosjs library in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

./cleos.sh set account permission account-name owner new-public-key -p account-name@owner

thank you Pete BlockMatrix for providing the answer on telegram