# How to manage accounts on EOS mainnet?

Tags: accounts, mainnet, account-name, keys

I registered an account name on EOS mainnet and I have `cleos` and other tools installed locally. How can I add/delete/change private keys and transfer EOS tokens to other accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Description of adding/changing private keys is [available here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/874/how-can-you-add-or-change-the-keys-for-the-owner-of-an-account/878#878).
To transfer EOS tokens using cleos, use:

`cleos -u <RPC API URL> transfer <sender account name> <recipient account name> '<EOS amount> EOS' <[optional] memo>`

`cleos -u https://api.tokenika.io transfer aaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb '1 EOS'`